# Are there any *official* Windows 10 ISO images using install.esd instead of install.wim?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, installer

I [know](https://techjourney.net/decrypt-convert-upgrade-esd-to-create-bootable-windows-iso-or-wim/) *I* can create Windows 10 installers that use encrypted-and-compressed `install.esd` files rather than `install.wim` files, and I [know](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads/?#searchTerm=Windows%2010%20(Multiple%20Editions)) Microsoft distributes *official* ISO files that use `install.wim`.

However, I'm wondering if there are any officially-provided ISO images that have an `install.esd` file?

The reason being that I want to be able to keep the ISO files and validate their MD5/SHA1 checksums against well-known ones in the future, but since ESD files can be a couple of gigabytes smaller than WIM files, I'd prefer using those if possible. Do any such ISOs exist, or is creating them myself the only option?

Comment: @Moab: they're not ISO files...

Comment: @Moab: did you read the question?

Comment: Yes I did and I also know you have researched this extensively and already know the answer (no there is not), that is why a commented a workaround which I have no idea if you had a source for all esd files.